# Locking the camera in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python

I am creating a 2d mario style platformer using Ursina Engine, and I want to be able to lock the camera when the player goes left and stop the camera from tracking just the player. I looked through the documentation and it seems pretty barren. Anyone work with this game engine yet?

Answer (score 11):

You can set the camera position and rotation just like with any other Entity. This code will limit x to 0:

```
camera.x = max(camera.x, 0)
```

Or if you've parented the camera, you may want to set world position instead:

```
camera.world_x = max(camera.world_x, 0)
```

Comment: Are you the pokepetter that made Ursina itself as it says on GitHub? If so, as I have no GitHub account to report it, there is a bug I have run into that there seems to be no solution to. Is this normal?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873751/why-cant-i-load-a-obj-file-into-python-ursina/66942136#66942136
I really appreciate anything you could do to help if you are the pokepetter that made it. You seem to know lots about Ursina.

Comment: @Password-Classified, it seems like the only problem was the scale, so what bug are you talking about ? The scale is small because the model is small.

Comment: It wasn't I asked on github after creating an account and it turns out I have to triangulate the models. @DiamondsBattle

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `if` statement to clarify what you want and use a `previous_x` variable.

```py
    prev_x = camera.x

    def update(): #the following code should be added to your update function which is already called...

        if prev_x < camera.x:
        
            lock() 
#this should be a function which is linked
#to your code which moves the camera. 
#A way to do this would be to set a 
#certain variable to true and use the following code:

locked = False
if not locked:
    function_which_moves_camera_left()
    
#The lock() function would be:

def lock():
    locked = True
    
#You could unlock it with the function:

def unlock():
    locked = False
```

So...

> By using **an `if` statement**, you can create a function using a `variable` as a `flag`. Checking this allows you to lock the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Just add camera.position and camera.rotation:

```
camera.position=(1, 10, -10)
camera.rotation=(1, 10, -10)
```