# Why can't I load a .OBJ file into Python Ursina?

Tags: python, file, 3d, game-engine, panda3d

I am using the python Ursina engine. I want to import a .OBJ file, but it never works, yet no errors are raised. I have tried:

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.mesh_importer import *

app = Ursina()

model123 = load_model('model123.obj')
model123Entity = Entity(model=model123)
    
def update():
    move()

EditorCamera()
app.run()
```

I have also tried it without the .obj ending.
Any help?

I have now tried:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.mesh_importer import *

app = Ursina()

model123 = load_model(obj_to_ursinamesh('model123.obj'))
model123_Entity = Entity(model=model123)

app.run()
```

I get the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'
AL lib: (EE) ALCwasapiPlayback_mixerProc: WaitForSingleObjectEx error: 0x102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is triangulation. The models faces must only be triangles. You can do this in **Blender** or other 3d software of that such type. I got this information thanks to Pokepetter on Github, at [this issue](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues/204).

For example, consider using **Blender**, or other software similar, to create your models and use the *triangulate* modifier on meshes to make them compatible with Ursina Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I load my OBJ model like here. It is working.

```
mymodel=Entity(model="tree.obj",scale=0.1, texture=("Grass.png"))
```

Comment: Yes but this was for a specific error. This is a general solution and does not apply for this error. The Triangulation solution was the successful response